# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE error during gradle artifactoryPublish task

Tags: gradle, plugins, dependencies, war, artifactory

We're trying to migrate our project configured with gradle 4.0 into gradle 5.6 (latest). Looks like there's a dependency issue with httpclient (apache) component that generate this exception during the Publish of the war package.

This is a gradle project, root (container) project has included a war plugin for packaging, jfrog artifactory 4.9.8 for publishing, all the subprojects are java projects with their dependency list provided (included httpclient 4.5.9 and httpcore 4.4.11).

```
-- root
plugins {
    id 'war'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'org.sonarqube' version '2.7'
    id 'net.researchgate.release' version '2.6.0'
    id 'com.github.spotbugs' version '2.0.0' apply false
    id 'com.jfrog.artifactory' version '4.9.8'
}

-- subprojects
dependencies {
      ..
      compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.9'
      ..
      configurations.all {
            force 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.11'
            force 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.9'
      }
}
```

./gradlew artifactoryPublish

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':artifactoryDeploy'.

  > INSTANCE

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<clinit>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:144)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.getDefaultRegistry(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:109)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:116)
        at org.jfrog.build.client.PreemptiveHttpClient.<init>(PreemptiveHttpClient.java:57)
        at org.jfrog.build.client.ArtifactoryHttpClient.getHttpClient(ArtifactoryHttpClient.java:145)
        at org.jfrog.build.client.ArtifactoryHttpClient.getHttpClient(ArtifactoryHttpClient.java:140)
        at org.jfrog.build.client.ArtifactoryHttpClient.executeGetRequest(ArtifactoryHttpClient.java:184)
        at org.jfrog.build.client.ArtifactoryHttpClient.getVersion(ArtifactoryHttpClient.java:154)
        at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBaseClient.getArtifactoryVersion(ArtifactoryBaseClient.java:109)
        at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.tryChecksumDeploy(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:705)
        at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.uploadFile(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:664)
        at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.doDeployArtifact(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:367)
        at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.deployArtifact(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:355)
        at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.deployArtifact(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:340)
        at org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.task.DeployTask.deployArtifacts(DeployTask.java:262)
        at org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.task.DeployTask.prepareAndDeploy(DeployTask.java:113)
        at org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.task.DeployTask.collectProjectBuildInfo(DeployTask.java:50)
        at org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.task.DeployTask.taskAction(DeployTask.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:103)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:49)
```

Comment: My guess is that one of the other plugins your project uses, is using a different version of the apache http client. I would try finding that plugin threw elimination. Once found, check which plugin uses the older version of the client and then, ask the plugin maintainers to upgrade it.

Comment: Looks like I cannot come out from this dependency resolution, because the project is using "sardine" (for WebDav), "smiley-http-proxy-servlet" and "jfrog-gradle-plugin". Unfortunately the "sardine" latest artifact (5.9) depends on org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient version 4.5.1 while the others has 4.5.2... I tried to force usage of 4.5.2 or 4.5.1 but I get the same error during "artifactoryPublish" task!!